# Resize views imported from another view - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, swiftui

I am trying to lay out a view with data from my data model and another view but I am struggling to resize the imported view. As you can see from the image below the table I have made in a separate view is taking over the full-frame.

I have tried to resize it in my master view where I am pulling everything together but no luck. I have also tried the `scaleEffect` modifier but that only scales the content in the view and keeps the view bounding regions the same scale.

Ideally, I would like to resize the table down so there is an even split between the paragraph and table. Also, apologies for the large amount of code shared here but I want to share all the formatting I have used incase there is something in there that is stopping me get the desired result.

The below image is displayed on an iPad which is where the app is being distributed.

[image: Example of what is happening in the view]

Here is where I am pulling all the data together:

```
  struct Tab1Section08: View {
    
    var product: ProductModel
    let frameHeight: CGFloat = 900
    let title = "This is a title"
    let subtitle = "This is a subtitle"
    let paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    
    struct Tab1Section08: View {
    let frameHeight: CGFloat = 900
    let title = "This is a title"
    let subtitle = "This is a subtitle"
    let paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color(red: 0.97, green: 0.97, blue: 0.97)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .frame(height: frameHeight)
            VStack {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.custom("Avenir-Black", size: 30))
                    .padding(.top, 60)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                HStack{
                    VStack {
                        Text(subtitle)
                            .font(.custom("Avenir-Black", size: 20))
                        Text(paragraph)
                            .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 16))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            .lineSpacing(10)
                            .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    }
                    VStack {
                        Tab1Section08ListRow()
                            .padding(.bottom, 20)
                        Text(subtitle)
                            .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 12))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a view where I am creating the table:

```
    struct Tab1Section08ListRow: View {
        
        let color: Color = .gray
        let width: CGFloat = 1
        let textPadding: CGFloat = 5
        let frameWidth: CGFloat = 250
        let amount: CGFloat = 3
        let title = ["first", "second","third"]
        let columns = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]
        
        var body: some View {
            let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(title.count)*40
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    ForEach(0..<title.count, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(title[item])
                            .font(.custom("Avenir-Heavy", size: 18))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .frame(width: frameWidth)
                            .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    }
                }
                HStack{
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        ForEach(0..<columns.count, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(columns[item])
                                .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 14))
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .frame(width: frameWidth)
                                .padding(.bottom, textPadding)
                                .padding(.top, textPadding)
                        }
                    }
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(color)
                        .frame(width: width, height: height)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        ForEach(0..<columns.count, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(columns[item])
                                .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 14))
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .frame(width: frameWidth)
                                .padding(.bottom, textPadding)
                                .padding(.top, textPadding)
                        }
                    }
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(color)
                        .frame(width: width, height: height)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        ForEach(0..<columns.count, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(columns[item])
                                .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 14))
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .frame(width: frameWidth)
                                .padding(.bottom, textPadding)
                                .padding(.top, textPadding)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried multiplying each element by the scale factor?

Comment: Yes that doesn't work. The bounding box still stays the same for the view I am importing.

Comment: Change the font in the stacks?

Comment: Can you set your code up with some hard wired data? It is difficult to play with in Xcode without knowing what your product model is, at least as far as this view is concerned. I am a bit bothered by all of the fixed numbers for the .frame()s. That can lead to unexpectedly bad things happening at times.

Comment: @Yrb I have updated the post so it can be recreated.

Comment: You left `Product` in, and it is intrinsic to the views, but it has no data to run. I would make a new project, transfer your problem code over, and make sure it builds. Then post again.

Comment: @Yrb Ah sorry! Its updated now. I have tested it in a new project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected from the beginning it is your fixed frames. If I comment out `.frame(width: frameWidth)` the view collapses to give your "lorem ipsum" view more room.
With `.frame(width: frameWidth)`:
[image]

And without:
[image]

Hard coding frames like that messes with SwiftUI's ability to handle the different sizes. I would consider using a geometry reader and expressing the widths a percentage of screen size.

Comment: Yes I get the same on an iPod and iPhone but my initial question is presented on an iPad.

Comment: To be fair, I only just added it now incase someone else viewed it...

Comment: Amazing thanks. I really need to get my head around geometry reader and start using it.